# Odd USB issue after idle

Tags: usb, suspend, idle

Sometimes when my machine goes idle I lose the ability to connect new USB devices to it.  When this happens any USB devices that are currently connected continue to work, but anything new that is plugged in fails to be recognized.

This only started recently and it has been difficult to troubleshoot.  I have a USB hub that switches my keyboard and mouse from my desktop to my laptop while I am working during the day and sometimes when I try to switch back to the desktop running Ubuntu they are not recognized.  Rebooting the desktop fixes the issue and it will work fine for a while but will eventually fail again.

I plugged another usb keyboard into the desktop and that will keep working so I can pull up a terminal, but I do not have another mouse so I have not been able to resize terminal windows / scroll to really see much of the error messages and logs.  I just ordered another usb mouse so hopefully I can provide more details soon.  Any advice on where to start is appreciated.

The keyboard is wired, the mouse is wireless.  The USB switch disconnects the usb devices from one device and connects them to the other so from the device perspective it is like they were unplugged, then if the desktop goes idle it will no longer recognize any new devices that are plugged into it.

An example - I hit the button on the usb switch to move over to my laptop.  Work there for a while and when I come back to the desktop (after it going idle) the keyboard and mouse are not recognized.  If I try plugging in a different usb keyboard, usb drive, etc they will not be recognized however if a usb keyboard was plugged into the desktop before it went idle that will keep working fine but no other new devices will work.

---

The issue has happened two more times since I originally posted this, but the behavior has gotten exceedingly worse.  In addition to new USB devices not being recognized, simple things like opening the file explorer, or notepad++ stopped working.

I pulled up dmesg and each time found an error message:

```
Unable to handle page fault for address: xxxxxxxxx
Supervisor write access in kernel mode
error code (ox0002) - not-present page
```

Followed by lots of errors where it looks like the system is trying to kill and restart the systemd-journald.service but is unable it will state that the process remains after sigkill and ignoring, but then will say `***failed to start the Journal Service***`

After issuing a restart from the terminal the screen fills with other services that are attempting to kill, they fail and ignore.  I let that run for 10+ minutes and had to hold the power down to get it restarted.

Each time this happened I did a `dmesg > mydmesg`, verified that the file was there and opened it using nano, but post reboot the file is gone.

I will keep trying to grab the output from dmesg and journalctl while the issue is occurring but it has been a trick.  It also seems that the idle time has nothing to do with the issue, as it happened once today when switching back and forth between computers before the desktop had gone idle.

---

It looks like this is where the error is starting.  There is more information displayed in the live dmesg outuput when the issue is occcuring, but I think the kworker exiting abruptly at the end prevents anything additional from being written to journalctl?

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QnXDY2nw5B/ (full error log)

Comment: It sounds like you are using a switch between your Human interface devices and your computers. If you remove the switch and connect the keyboard and mouse directly to the system go you get the same result? On both the desktop and the laptop? On both the keyboard and the mouse? Are the aforementioned devices wireless or wired? Please [edit] your question to include this information. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: added some details to the question, but I believe you could take the usb switch out of the equation.  If I unplugged usb devices and let the desktop go idle, new devices would no longer be recognized, but anything currently connected keeps working fine.

My setup is too complicated to physically remove the usb switch out of the equation, but my theory is that it is not a factor.  When switching between laptop and desktop the usb devices are disconnected from one and connected to the other.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I understand what you believe, however I haven't seen enough information to eliminate the switch (or for that matter, the USB port it's plugged into from the list of possible problems.) I've seen a lot of mangled hardware in my decades of experience, and refuse to eliminate that as a possibility simply because you believe that isn't the case. I'm voting to close based on a lack of information. If you [edit] the output of `lsusb` to your question showing before and after you are forced to use a different keyboard that might be useful, but as it stands, there's not enough.

Comment: When this occurs, do you see anything unusual in the journal for the systemd-udevd service (ex. `journalctl -xe -u systemd-udevd`) ?

Comment: @Elder geek it is not the usb port for sure, I have tried moving the usb switch to different ports when the issue occurs and there is no difference. I have also tried swapping the usb outputs on the switch and the problem follows the desktop pc regardless of which port it is plugged into.

Devices plugged directly into other usb ports on the desktop are also unrecognized when the issue occurs.  So a different keyboard, or usb drive plugged directly into the desktop pc will not work even if the switch is first disconnected.

Comment: @steeldriver I will pull the output the next time it happens along with the output from lsusb before and after.  It is pretty intermittent so it may be a little while

Comment: @steeldriver I added some additional info above. I was unable to save off the journalctl info, but it looked pretty similar to when the system is "healthy".  I uploaded the results here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XrnXNggMv9/

Comment: Perhaps these (RedHat) kernel bug reports are relevant? [Bug 2227221 - USB disconnect causes kernel crash](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2227221) and its [Bug 2227968 - power_supply_uevent on USB leads to page_fault_oops](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2227968)

Comment: @steeldriver that first one looks exactly right.. I tried unplugging and re-plugging the logitech usb dongle a bunch of times as well as swapping back and forth with the USB hub normally but could not reproduce the issue today but couldn't.

Wondering what the path to resolution is if that is the case... I don't know if recompiling the kernel is in my comfort zone at this point... I assume a lot of people are using wireless logitech usb devices and this would be high on the radar, but it seems kernel updates are every 6 months generally speaking?

Comment: This only started in the last month or so, and I have been using the same hardware setup with the usb switch for at least 2 years.  Any recommendations on how to identify the update that caused the issue?  or am I stuck recompiling the kernel or waiting for a kernel update that addresses the issue directly?